# How to define new 2D-structure in Quantum ATK?

Tags: quantum-atk

I will define a new structure in Quantum ATK that is unavailable in the database.

I tried this file to give information to the application, but it didn't work.

```
################################################################################
# -------------------------------------------------------------
# Bulk Configuration
# -------------------------------------------------------------

# Set up lattice
lattice = Hexagonal(6.2791373697288*Angstrom, 31.395686849*Angstrom)

# Define elements
elements = [Indium, Indium, Silicon, Silicon , Sulfur, Sulfur,
            Sulfur, Sulfur, Sulfur, Sulfur]

# Define coordinates
fractional_coordinates = [[2.100860978   0.000000000   2.83570303],
                         [2.100860978  0.000000000  0.566618954],
                         [5.240428412   1.812630103   1.701160992],
                         [2.100860978  3.625260206   1.701160992],
                         [3.139567435   1.799092358   3.402321984],
                         [4.201721956   3.638797952    0         ],
                         [1.062154521   1.799092358   0         ],
                         [0             3.638797952   3.402321984],
                         [4.178273892   0.000000000    0         ],
                         [6.302582933   0.000000000   3.402321984]]

# Set up configuration
bulk_configuration = BulkConfiguration(
    bravais_lattice=lattice,
    elements=elements,
    fractional_coordinates=fractional_coordinates
    )
    ##################################################################################
```

Comment: +1 Welcome to our forum!

Comment: My recommendation if to add the 3D structure to the builder window and then, cut it in the direction you want, and then add the corresponding periodic conditions.